# Suppose $X_n$ is a record value. Will $F(X_n)$ be a record value as well?

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-function

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with distribution $F$. We say that a record occurs at time $n,n>0$ and has values $X_n$ if $X_n > \max (X_1,\cdots X_{n-1})$

**Suppose $X_n$ is a record value. Will $F(X_n)$ be a record value as well?** My book says that the record times of the sequence $\{X_1,\cdots,X_n\}$ will be the same as for the sequence $F(X_1),\cdots,F(X_n)$

**Attempt:** $X_n$ is a record value implies $X_n > \max (X_1,\cdots X_{n-1})$. Let the value obtained at time $t$ be $x_n$

> We need to find if $F(X_n) > \max (F(X_1),\cdots,F(X_{n-1}))$

Now, $F(X_n = y) = \mathbb P(X_n \leq y) = \int_{-\infty} ^{y} f_X(x) dx$

$(X_i)'s$ are i.i.d random variables.

Now, my confusion is that $F$ is an increasing function. It cannot possibly have a record value as such. Could someone clear this for me.

Comment: My guess is that all your book want to say if, say, the 7th value is the largest, then, because (as you say) $F$ is increasing $F(X_7)$ will also be the largest of the $F(X_i)$.

Comment: I think this is a counterexample: suppose the $X_i$ are uniformly distributed on the union of closed intervals $[0,1] \cup [2, 3]$, and that $X_1 = 1$ and $X_2 = 2$. Then $X_2$ is a record but $F(X_2) = F(X_1) = 0.5$. (Though the probability of encountering a counterexample like this is zero.)